# VBA - SQL Server 2014 - How to access localhost - Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, vba, localhost

**VBA - SQL Server 2014 - How to access localhost?**

Pretty much, I need to access localhost of SQL Server and I have tried almost anything I found here:

[What is the sql connection string I need to use to access localhost\SQLEXPRESS with Windows Authentication or SQL Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283727/what-is-the-sql-connection-string-i-need-to-use-to-access-localhost-sqlexpress-w)

I have tried this:

```
    str_connection_string = "Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Tempt;Integrated Security=True;"
    str_connection_string = "Data Source = .\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Tempt;Integrated Security=True;"
```

And both return error:

[image]

This is a German Run-Time error, saying something about OLE DB. (My German is also not in my top 4 languages).

I want WindowsAuthetication. The automatic one, without username or password.

So what are the ideas?
I use MSSQL Management Studio 2014.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

A day has passed. this is what I tried in the morning:
@GuidoG
I liked the idea, but I did not succeed to make it in a way. What should be the servername on the top (point 1), in order to find my DB (point 3)?

### [image]

@Comintern
The local server, to which I am connecting through the MS DB Studio looks like this:

### (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Edit: I am trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: "Data Source= **YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME** \SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Tempt;Integrated Security=True;"

Comment: Hi. It really does not work. Same mistake. I have taken the YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME from here >Systemsteuerung\Alle Systemsteuerungselemente\System<

Comment: create a txt file. Rename its extension to .UDL Now doubleclick on it and you will get a screen where you can build and test your connectionstring. If you have a tested connectionstring than save it and then open the text file with notepad to see the completed connectionstring

Comment: What does the "SERVER\INSTANCE" look like when you connect to the database engine in SSMS?

Comment: @Comintern see the update of the post.

Comment: @GuidoG - see the update of the post.

Comment: You are using an ADO.NET connection string. OLEDB connection strings *have* to specify the driver they want to use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to SQL Server using OLEDB using Windows Authentication connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913409/how-do-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-oledb-using-windows-authentication-connecti)

Comment: Can you show us the first tab of this screen ? What are you using there ? OLE DB for SQL Server or Sql Server Native Client ? For local db it should be the latter

Comment: Now I am using the Sql Server Native Client. With a server name "MSSQLLocalDB" I cannot find any db to select. And what should I write in the Server SPN?

Comment: In localDB you cannot select a database from the server, you have to use second option at the bottom of the screen and select your mdf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is what has worked for me:

```
connectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Tempt;Trusted_Connection=yes;timeout=30;"
```

My db is named "Tempt".
I have taken the code from here:
https://sysmod.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/adodb-connection-string-for-localdb-and-sql-server-native-client/

Thanks everyone for the help! :)

Comment: The mixed feeling 2 years later, when you google the same problem and find your own answer...

Comment: You'r lucky; me usually finds only my own questions, without any solutions :)

Comment: @Arvo - yup. And the answer has actually helped me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try stating the driver like the below in the VBA connection string. You will find server\instance right below the connect bar (in object explorer) in SSMS.

```
"SERVER=[server]\[instance];DRIVER={SQL Server};Initial Catalog=[database];Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

Comment: I think you posted an ODBC connection string. OLEDB connection strings require a `Provider` parameter instead of `DRIVER`

Comment: True that, @Panagiotis KAnavos. I am until here:https://sysmod.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/adodb-connection-string-for-localdb-and-sql-server-native-client/  And I am looking for Provider. Any idea?

Comment: For localDB the provider should be a "SQL Server Native Client". If you dont have this you can download it from microsoft but it takes some searching

Comment: I am trying this: >Provider=SQL Server Native Client;Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Tempt;Trusted_Connection=Yes;< but it does not work.

Comment: @Vityata did you try googling for `OLEDB SQL Server Connection String" ? Or check the documentation? There are a lot of resources, eg [this one](https://connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/)

Comment: well, I did not find a way to refer a local db in the link.