# Failure when get data from sql to excel

Tags: excel, vba

ive tried many things to make this but i have no ideia how to fix it, i want to import sql users table to excel, im using this code :

> "Runtime Error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Automation Error Unspecified
>   Error"

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim connstr As String
Dim strSRV As String
Dim strDB As String
Dim sql_login As String


sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM users" ' Enter your SQL here


connstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=PTrails_Core_DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

'Create the Connection and Recordset objects
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = connstr
conn.Open
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running on your machine?

Comment: Try to change the DataSource to `Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` [as in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39369312/5448626). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SQL Server to Excel:

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "your_server_name" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "Northwind" ' Enter your  database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM Orders" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z500")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or...

```
Sub ImportFromSQLServer()

' Create a connection object.
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=(local);INITIAL CATALOG=NORTHWIND.MDF;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

'Now open the connection.
cnPubs.Open strConn

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsPubs
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    ' Extract the required records.
    .Open "SELECT * FROM Categories"
    ' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs

    ' Tidy up
    .Close
End With

cnPubs.Close
Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Or...

```
Sub ImportFromSQLServer()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "your_server_name"
Database_Name = "Northwind"
'User_ID = "******"
'Password = "****"

SQLStr = "select * from dbo.TBL where EMPID = '2'" 'and PostingDate = '2006-06-08'"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"
'& ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

RS.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With

RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit

Public Const NUMBER_OF_BRANCHES = 8
Public Const FIRST_ROW = 4

Public Const SHEET_INSURANCE = "Insurance"
Public Const SHEET_REPEAT_LOANS = "RepeatLoans"

Sub Execute()

    ClearContent SHEET_INSURANCE
    ExtractData SHEET_INSURANCE
    AutoFillFormulas SHEET_INSURANCE

    ClearContent SHEET_REPEAT_LOANS
    ExtractDataRepeatLoans SHEET_REPEAT_LOANS
    AutoFillFormulas SHEET_REPEAT_LOANS

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Private Sub ClearContent(ByVal sheet As String)

    Sheets(sheet).Select

    Rows(CStr(FIRST_ROW + 1) & ":" & CStr(GetLastRow(sheet))).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A" & CStr(FIRST_ROW) & ":" & "N" & CStr(FIRST_ROW)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub

Private Sub AutoFillFormulas(ByVal sheet As String)

    Dim rangeSource As String
    rangeSource = "O" & CStr(FIRST_ROW) & ":" & "Q" & CStr(FIRST_ROW)

    Dim rangeDestination As String
    rangeDestination = "O" & CStr(FIRST_ROW) & ":" & "Q" & CStr(GetLastRowOfColumn("A", sheet))

    AutoFill rangeSource, rangeDestination, sheet

End Sub

Private Sub ExtractData(ByVal sheet As String)

    Dim cnx As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command


    Set cnx = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    Sheets(sheet).Select

    Dim dateFrom As String
    dateFrom = Range("NM_DATE_FROM").Value

    Dim dateTo As String
    dateTo = Range("NM_DATE_TO").Value

    cnx.ConnectionString = "UID=angelalihusha;PWD=Prov1921*;DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=" & Range("DB_SERVER").Value & ";Database=" & Range("DB_NAME").Value & ";"
    cnx.Open

    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from( " & _
                        "select case when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 200000 then 1 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >=200000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 300000 then 2 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 300000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 400000 then 3 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 400000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 500000 then 4 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 500000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 600000 then 5 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 600000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 700000 then 6 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 700000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 800000 then 7 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 800000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 900000 then 8 end as Branch, " & _
                        "loanDisbursement.client_number, loanDisbursement.CLIENT_NAME, loanDisbursement.IND_SEXO, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),loanDisbursement.FECH_NACIMIENTO,101) as birthDate, " & _
                        "(select top 1 NUM_ID from cl.CL_ID_CLIENTES where cl.CL_ID_CLIENTES.COD_CLIENTE  = loandisbursement.client_number and cl.CL_ID_CLIENTES.COD_TIPO_ID = 104) as NRC, " & _
                        "case when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 200000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >=200000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 300000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 200000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 300000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 400000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 300000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 400000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 500000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 400000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 500000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 600000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 500000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 600000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 700000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 600000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 700000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 800000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 700000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 800000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 900000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 800000 " & _
                        "end as loan_number , " & _
                        " case when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (1,5,10) then 'Women market trader' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (3,7,12) then 'MSME' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (4,8,9,13) then 'Home improvement' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (2,6,11) then 'Consumer' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (14) then 'Employee Liquidity' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (15) then 'Employee Asset' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (16,17) then 'Salary Backed' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (18) then 'Employee Educational' else 'N/A' end as LoanType, " & _
                        "loanDisbursement.DURATION,loanDisbursement.loan_amount, loanDisbursement.OPENING_DATE,loanDisbursement.STATUS,case when loanDisbursement.REPEAT_LOAN = 1 then 'Yes' when loanDisbursement.REPEAT_LOAN is null then 'No' end as RepeatLoan, " & _
                        "isnull((select MON_MOVIMIENTO  from PR.PR_MOVIMIENTOS where NUM_CREDITO = loanDisbursement.loan_number and TIP_TRANSACCION = 1 and SUB_TIP_TRANSACCION = 1 and NUM_IDENTIF = 3),0) as insurance " & _
                        "from dbo.Loan_disbursement_extra as loanDisbursement " & _
                        "left join pr.PR_CREDITOS as credit on loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER = credit.NUM_CREDITO " & _
                        ") as temp " & _
                        "where  " & _
                            "OPENING_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'" & dateFrom & "', 103)  and OPENING_DATE < CONVERT(DATETIME,'" & dateTo & "', 103) " & _
                        "order by branch, loan_number "


    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx

    Set rst = cmd.Execute


    ActiveSheet.Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing

    cnx.Close

End Sub


Private Sub ExtractDataRepeatLoans(ByVal sheet As String)

    Dim cnx As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

    Set cnx = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    Sheets(sheet).Select

    Dim dateFrom As String
    dateFrom = Range("NM_DATE_FROM").Value

    Dim dateTo As String
    dateTo = Range("NM_DATE_TO").Value

    cnx.ConnectionString = "UID=angelalihusha;PWD=Prov1921*;DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=" & Range("DB_SERVER").Value & ";Database=" & Range("DB_NAME").Value & ";"
    cnx.Open

    cmd.CommandText = "Select Branch, client_number, CLIENT_NAME, IND_SEXO, FECH_NACIMIENTO, NRC, loan_number, LoanType,DURATION,LOAN_AMOUNT,OPENING_DATE,STATUS,repeatLoan, insurance from( " & _
                        "select case when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 200000 then 1 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >=200000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 300000 then 2 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 300000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 400000 then 3 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 400000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 500000 then 4 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 500000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 600000 then 5 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 600000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 700000 then 6 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 700000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 800000 then 7 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 800000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 900000 then 8 end as Branch, " & _
                        "loanDisbursement.client_number, loanDisbursement.CLIENT_NAME, loanDisbursement.IND_SEXO, loanDisbursement.FECH_NACIMIENTO, " & _
                        "(select top 1 NUM_ID from cl.CL_ID_CLIENTES where cl.CL_ID_CLIENTES.COD_CLIENTE  = loandisbursement.client_number and cl.CL_ID_CLIENTES.COD_TIPO_ID = 104) as NRC, " & _
                        "case when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 200000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >=200000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 300000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 200000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 300000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 400000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 300000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 400000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 500000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 400000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 500000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 600000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 500000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 600000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 700000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 600000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 700000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 800000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 700000 when loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER >= 800000 and loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER < 900000 then loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER - 800000 " & _
                        "end as loan_number , " & _
                        " case when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (1,5,10) then 'Women market trader' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (3,7,12) then 'MSME' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (4,8,9,13) then 'Home improvement' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (2,6,11) then 'Consumer' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (14,15) then 'Employee' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (16,17) then 'Salary Backed' when loandisbursement.LOAN_TYPE IN (18) then 'Employee Educational' else 'N/A' end as LoanType, " & _
                        "loanDisbursement.DURATION,loanDisbursement.loan_amount, loanDisbursement.OPENING_DATE,loanDisbursement.STATUS,case when loanDisbursement.REPEAT_LOAN = 1 then 'Yes' when loanDisbursement.REPEAT_LOAN is null then 'No' end as RepeatLoan, " & _
                        "isnull((select MON_MOVIMIENTO  from PR.PR_MOVIMIENTOS where NUM_CREDITO = loanDisbursement.loan_number and TIP_TRANSACCION = 1 and SUB_TIP_TRANSACCION = 1 and NUM_IDENTIF = 3),0) as insurance , " & _
                        "loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER as loan_number_branch " & _
                        "from dbo.Loan_disbursement_extra as loanDisbursement " & _
                        "left join pr.PR_CREDITOS as credit on loanDisbursement.LOAN_NUMBER = credit.NUM_CREDITO " & _
                        ") as temp " & _
                        "Where " & _
                            "temp.loan_number_branch in (select max(NUM_CREDITO) from pr.pr_creditos " & _
                                                    "Where COD_CLIENTE in (select client_number from Loan_disbursement_extra where OPENING_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'" & dateFrom & "', 103) and  OPENING_DATE < CONVERT(DATETIME,'" & dateTo & "', 103) and repeat_loan = 1) " & _
                                                    "and NUM_CREDITO not in (select LOAN_NUMBER  from Loan_disbursement_extra where OPENING_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'" & dateFrom & "', 103) and OPENING_DATE < CONVERT(DATETIME,'" & dateTo & "', 103) and repeat_loan = 1) " & _
                                                    "group by cod_cliente) " & _
                        "order by branch, loan_number"


    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx

    Set rst = cmd.Execute

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing

    cnx.Close

End Sub
```

..........................................................................................